# Remove all elements in an array after the first instance of an element that matches same alphabetic (ONLY) value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to remove all elements in the array that comes after the FIRST instance of an element that matches same string value before the dot`.` ie, not taking into consideration any values after the `.`

from

```
$array = ("ItemNew1.1", "Item2.0", "Item3Test.0", "Item2.2", "Item4.4", "Item2.5")
```

to

```
$array = ("ItemNew1.1", "Item2.0", "Item3Test.0", "Item4.4")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below creates a temp array to hold the values that are already in the array, it runs a foreach on the original array and if the value is not in the temporary array, it inserts it into a new array

```
$tempArray = array();
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $value) {
    list($item, ) = explode(".", $value);
    $int = filter_var($item, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if(!in_array($int, $tempArray)) {
        $newArray[] = $value;
        $tempArray[] = $int;
    }
}
```

Now, `$newArray` is the array that you want.

[**DEMO**](http://3v4l.org/KdWLK)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just updated my question to make it clearer. But strings may not necissarily be "Item5.2" it can be anything like, "RandomString.2"

Comment: @user2993497 Can the number be double digits or is it only 1 digit?

Comment: My number will only be 1 digit. But it would be interesting as well, to see a solution that caters for all numbers.

Comment: @user2993497 The solution caters for all numbers.